# Dual of dual of planar graph $G$ is isomorphic to $G$ if and only if $G$ is connected.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-isomorphism

I have been asked to show that the dual of the dual, $(G^*)^*$, of a planar graph $G$ is isomorphic to $G$ if and only if $G$ is connected.

I understand the reasoning in the [answer one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642841/why-is-a-connected-planar-graph-isomorphic-to-its-double-dual) but that cannot be the whole proof, right? I also know that $|E(G)|=2|V(G)|-2$ which is mentioned in the comments of [answer two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560536/a-planar-graph-g-is-the-dual-of-its-dual-if-and-only-if-g-is-connected). My idea is that I should try to show that any neighboring vertices in $G$ will also be neighboring vertices in $(G^*)^*$ (like in answer one), non-neighboring vertices in $G$ will be non-neighboring vertices in $(G^*)^*$ and that there will be the same number of vertices in both $G$ and $G^*$ but I cant really see what the conectedness gives. Is this correct and enough? Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: The dual of any finite graph is connected,because it is always possible to get to the "outside", so the direction you are missing is "easy".

Comment: Do you mean that all we have to assume of $G$ is that it is planar and finite for $G^*$ to be connected? 
And that the "easy" direction is the one I vaguely described with neighboring vertices becoming neighboring faces which goes back to be neighboring vertices again?

Comment: No, I mean that if $G$ is not connected then $G^{**}$ is.

Comment: Oh, okay so that is why the connectedness is important, now I understand what you mean. Any thoughts on my idea about the proof, is it enough?

Comment: $|E(G)|=2|V(G)|-2$ is for a different situation: for the situation where $G^*$ is isomorphic to $G$ (which usually doesn't happen). That comment is confused.